# Show that $g$ is increasing over $I$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $0 < \alpha < 1$. Let $g(x) = \alpha x + x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) = 0$. Show that $g'(0) > 0$ but there is no interval $I$ containing $0$ such that $g$ is increasing over $I$.

**Attempt**

We have that $\displaystyle g'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(x)}{x} =\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\left( \alpha + x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right) = \alpha >0$. Then to show the increasing part we need to show that we can't have an interval $(a,b)$ such that $g(x) \leq g(y)$ for all $x<y$ in $(a,b)$ where $a<0<b$. I am not sure how to show this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, with $I=[0,b]$ consider $x>0$, for which $g'(x) = \alpha + 2x \sin\frac1x - \cos\frac1x $. Take $x_0$ so small that $\alpha + 2|x_0| < \beta < 1$. Then for $0<x<\min\{x_0,b\}$ we have $g'(x) \leq \beta - \cos\frac1x$.
Taking $0<x<\min\{x_0,b\}$ such that $\cos\frac{1}{x} = 1$ we find $g'(x) < 0$.
For such an $x$, by the definition of a limit there is $h>0$ small enough that $x+h < \min\{x_0,b\}$ and that $\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} < 0$, so that $g(x+h) < g(x)$. In particular $g$ is not increasing on $[0,b]$.

The fact that $f$ is an odd function finishes the proof.

Comment: Why are you showing for a particular interval $I$ and not all intervals?

Comment: Any nontrivial interval containing $0$ contains a smaller interval of the form $[0,b]$ or $[a,0]$ which is nontrivial. If $f$ isn't increasing on $[0,b]$, it will not be increasing on any bigger interval either.

Comment: What do you mean by "The fact that $f$ is an odd function finishes the proof"?

Comment: In the case that your interval contains an interval of the  form $[a,0]$, consider instead $[0,|a|]$ to get $x\in(0,|a|]$ and $h>0$ with $g(x+h) < g(x)$. But then since $g$ is odd we now have $-g(-x-h) < -g(-x)$ so that $g(-x) < g(-x-h)$ and again we find that $g$ is not increasing on $[a,0]$.

Comment: Didn't what you wrote above that prove it? Why did you need to mention it was odd?

Comment: I mention it because if your interval $I$ is of the form $[a,0]$ then it does not contain any nontrivial interval of the form $[0,b]$, so the first part doesn't apply.